# getting order_id in array codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting order ids in an array. ["00000421"].

Here is my code:

```
function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    log_message('error','get order_id==>'.$order_id);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('temp_transaction');
    $this->db->where('order_id', $order_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) 
    {
        log_message('error','inside if==>');
        return null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        log_message('error','Inside else==>');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

How can i get this like 000000421?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail in your question? What class are you using?

Comment: `$query->row()->order_id` should work if I understood your query properly

Comment: Do you have issue `$this->db->where('order_id', $order_id);` with this?

Comment: Yes. it is getting order_id like this ["0000421"]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from array then you can use `where_in` method

```
function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    log_message('error','get order_id==>'.$order_id);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('temp_transaction');
    $this->db->where_in('order_id', $order_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) 
    {
        log_message('error','inside if==>');
        return null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        log_message('error','Inside else==>');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. I got it. How do i ["00000421"] convert this into string?

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_similar_user_temp_transaction($order_id)
{
    log_message('error','get order_id==>'.$order_id);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('temp_transaction');
    $this->db->where('order_id', $order_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) 
    {
        log_message('error','inside if==>');
        return null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        log_message('error','Inside else==>');
        return $query->row(0)->order_id;
    }
}
```